# When showing WebBrowser in Tab it turns into Image

Tags: ios, codenameone

when showing **WebBrowser** in **Tab** on IOs the component turns into an image that is browser's screenshot. On Simulator is just fine. If I close the app on the device and come back - it becomes OK.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed now in git.  Will be available in next server update next week.
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/e17c39a6293125b4e136ed4b05fb5e20a8c3a82f

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/understanding-peer-native-components-why-codename-one-is-so-portable.html) is a bit out of date by now but it might explain why that happens. If you move between the tabs the browser should be painted within the tab. So we turn it to an image and then turn it back.

The question is what happened that made it stay as an image?

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue. When swiping tabs, the browser stay as an image

Comment: See Steve's answer